# Is it possible to construct geometric graph based on weighted edge set?

Tags: python, graph, plot, networkx, traveling-salesman

I have an instance of the traveling salesman problem presented in form of the list describing the edge set in form [(from, to, distance)]. I want to plot all of the solutions that I generate and for more clarity I want to dispose all the vertices on plane so that all of edge-distance-equalities hold (in the assumption that all weights behold to the triangle's inequality and the graph is complete). Can it be achieved? Preferably with Python networkx package.

Comment: I do not quite get it, you want edges with the same weight to have the same length ?

Comment: Yes, and I want those edges that have greater weight to be greater in length than those with lower weights. I suppose that this graph exists (i.e. holds triangle inequality and is symmetric and dist(x, x) = 0).

Comment: Geometrically, it can be built by drawing circles with radiuses equal to the given weights and picking a new point on their intersection, but I wonder whether there exists a package which allows to do it out of the box.

Comment: I believe it is more complicated than that because imagine a simple case where the weight between nodes 1&2 is very small and between 2&3 is very large then normally the weight between 1&3 is huge but what if the given weight of the edge is small

Comment: In that case it would be unfeasible to  draw

Comment: Well, than it doesn't satisfy triangle inequality. I already told that I assume this edge set to be a set of valid distances.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry I missed that